# How to print an empty XML element in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I occasionally have to write simple perl scripts to export data from XML files into CSV files for loading into a database.

I am encountering a problem "print"ing an element that has no value.  Instead of just printing nothing, it prints the string "HASH(0x1ca05f8)" (or its siblings).

How do I stop it from doing this?

Below is the code that I am using, and the data that I am using.  Thanks,  --sw

parse.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

#create object
$xml = new XML::Simple;

#read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("$ARGV[0]", ForceArray=>1);

foreach $pr (@{$data->{product}})
{
  foreach $rv (@{$pr->{reviews}})
  {
    foreach $fr (@{$rv->{fullreview}})
    {
      print "$ARGV[1]", ",";
      print "$ARGV[2]", ",";
      print "$ARGV[3]", ",";
      print "$ARGV[4]", ",";
      print $pr->{"pageid"}->[0], ",";
      print $fr->{"status"}->[0], ",";
      print $fr->{"source"}->[0], ",";
      print $fr->{"createddate"}->[0], ",";
      print $fr->{"overallrating"}->[0], ",";
      print $fr->{"email_address_from_user"}->[0], ",";
      foreach $csg (@{$fr->{confirmstatusgroup}})
      {
        print join(";", @{$csg->{"confirmstatus"}});
      }


      print "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<product xsi:type="ProductWithReviews" locale="en_US">
<pageid>bshnbat612</pageid>
<reviews>
<fullreview>
<status>Approved</status>
<createddate>2014-03-28</createddate>
<source>email</source>
<confirmstatusgroup>
<confirmstatus>Verified Purchaser</confirmstatus>
<confirmstatus>Verified Reviewer</confirmstatus>
</confirmstatusgroup>
<overallrating>5</overallrating>
<email_address_from_user/>
</fullreview>
</reviews>
</product>
</products>
```

The output this creates:

```
,,,,bshnbat612,Approved,email,2014-03-28,5,HASH(0xe9fee8),Verified Purchaser;Verified Reviewer
```

In response to a suggestion made below, here is the Dumper output:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    'product' => [
    {
        'xsi:type' => 'ProductWithReviews',
        'reviews' => [
        {
            'fullreview' => [
            {
                'source' => [
                    'email'
                ],
                'email_address_from_user' => [
                {}
                ],
                    'overallrating' => [
                        '5'
                    ],
                    'confirmstatusgroup' => [
                    {
                        'confirmstatus' => [
                            'Verified Purchaser',
                        'Verified Reviewer'
                        ]
                    }
                    ],
                        'status' => [
                            'Approved'
                        ],
                        'createddate' => [
                            '2014-03-28'
                        ]
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
            'pageid' => [
                'bshnbat612'
            ],
            'locale' => 'en_US'
    }
    ]
};
```

Comment: use Data::Dumper; and print Dumper $data to see how it is parsing your XML.

Comment: You really should avoid `XML::Simple`. It makes any XML code much more complicated than it needs to be and gives rise to all sorts of problems like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`SuppressEmpty`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#SuppressEmpty-1-undef-in-out---handy) option that can be passed to XML::Simple.  Without it, XML::Simple will provide an empty hash for empty elements.  By calling `XMLin("$ARGV[0]", ForceArray=>1, SuppressEmpty=>1);` your output should be: `,,,,bshnbat612,Approved,email,2014-03-28,5,,Verified Purchaser;Verified Reviewer`

Answer (score 2):

OK, there's a big hint on the `XML::Simple` documentation:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

Personally though, I like `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub print_full_review {
    my ( $twig, $full_review ) = @_;
    my $pageid =
        $twig->root->get_xpath( '/products/product/pageid', 0 )->text;

    print join(
        ",",
        @ARGV[ 1 .. 4 ],
        $pageid,
        $full_review->first_child_text('status'),
        $full_review->first_child_text('source'),
        $full_review->first_child_text('createddate'),
        $full_review->first_child_text('overallrating'),
        $full_review->first_child_text('email_address_from_user'),
        join( ";",
            map { $_->text }
                $full_review->first_child('confirmstatusgroup')->children() )
        ),
        "\n";
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'fullreview' => \&print_full_review }
);
$twig->parsefile( $ARGV[0] );
```

The handlers 'print_full_review' is triggered each time the parser encounters a `fullreview` element (at any level in the tree - you can be more specific by setting it to process `/product/products/reviews/fullreview` if that's a problem).

This handler is passed the `fullreview` element for processing.

And from it we extract the values you seek.

```
join( ";",
    map { $_->text }
        $full_review->first_child('confirmstatusgroup')->children() )
```

Is a slightly more complicated way of doing:

```
my $confirmstatusgroup = $full_review -> first_child('confirmstatusgroup');
foreach my $confirmstatus ( $confirmstatusgroup -> children ) { 
    print $confirmstatus -> text,";";
}
```

But the code above produces your desired output, but without having to do any sort of 'suppressempty' fudges like you would with `XML::Simple`.